# How To Call finishAffinity() Outside Activity in android

Tags: java, android

I Want To Close My Application Specific Activity From Other Activity Of My App. So I Have Created A Java Class And Want Call To **finishAffinity()**. But It Is In Red Marked. I Don't Know How To Solve It.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found It How Do This :-

```
public class CheckInternet {

    public Activity activity;

    public CheckInternet(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

     public void closeApp(){
        activity.finishAffinity();
        System.exit(0);
     }
}
```